Algolia autocomplete field doesn't get populated after selection
I have built an app with VueJS 3 (Composition API) and the Quasar framework (2.14.5) and integrated Algolia (4.24.0) as my search engine (with vue-InstantSearch 4.8.4). It works as a charm.
In a next step I have built a Vue component to use Algolia’s autocomplete following the guidelines on the Algolia website. My goal is to have a search with dropdown to search for companies in my Algolia ‘companies’ index. I face 2 issues currently:

The dropdown shows applicable values when I start typing, so that works, but when I select a value from the suggestions with the mouse or by hitting Enter, the search field doesn’t get populated with the selected value. I have no idea why, because all sandbox examples I have seen work properly.
I don’t know how to log to the console what the value is that is selected from the suggestions in the dropdown.

Can you help?
My Vue component:
<template>
  <div id="autocomplete" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { algoliaSearchClient } from 'boot/algolia'
import { autocomplete, getAlgoliaResults } from '@algolia/autocomplete-js'
import { onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue'

import '@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic'

const INDEX_NAME = 'companies'

let autocompleteInstance = null

onMounted(async () => {
  if (autocompleteInstance) {
    autocompleteInstance.destroy()
  }

  autocompleteInstance = autocomplete({
    container: '#autocomplete',
    placeholder: 'Search company',
    getSources ({ query }) {
      return [{
        sourceId: INDEX_NAME,
        // getItemInputValue: ({ item }) => item.query,
        getItems () {
          const results = getAlgoliaResults({
            searchClient: algoliaSearchClient,
            queries: [{
              indexName: INDEX_NAME,
              query,
              params: {
                hitsPerPage: 5,
                attributesToSnippet: [],
                attributesToHighlight: ['name', 'city', 'country.label'],
                snippetEllipsisText: '…'
              }
            }]
          })

          // console.log('Algolia results: ', results)

          return results
        },
        templates: {
          item ({ item, components, html }) {
            return html`
              <div class="aa-ItemWrapper">
                <div class="aa-ItemContent">
                  <div class="aa-ItemContentBody">
                    <div class="aa-ItemContentTitle">
                      ${components.Highlight({
                        hit: item,
                        attribute: 'name'
                      })}
                    </div>
                    <div class="aa-ItemContentDescription">
                      ${components.Highlight({
                        hit: item,
                        attribute: 'city'
                      })}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="aa-ItemActions">
                    <button
                      class="aa-ItemActionButton aa-DesktopOnly aa-ActiveOnly"
                      type="button"
                      title="Select"
                    >
                      <svg
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        width="20"
                        height="20"
                        fill="currentColor"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M18.984 6.984h2.016v6h-15.188l3.609 3.609-1.406 1.406-6-6 6-6 1.406 1.406-3.609 3.609h13.172v-4.031z"
                        />
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            `
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  })
})

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  if (autocompleteInstance) {
    autocompleteInstance.destroy()
  }
})
</script>

The dropdown in the UI:

